# AWS Video Rekognation with SNS Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

As a front-end developer I'm currently facing an issue with AWS Rekognition and AWS SNS. I'm working on an application where users can upload videos through my web app to my S3 bucket.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: Once a file is uploaded to S3, I want to trigger another Lambda function, passing the fileName and userId as parameters.

This secondary Lambda function will then invoke the AWS Video Rekognition service to process the video and provide results.

I intend to store these results in my DynamoDB.

I'd appreciate it if you could review my approach and let me know if there are any logical mistakes or improvements I can make.

So far, here's what I've accomplished:

Lambda A:

```
const client = new RekognitionClient({ region: "us-east-1" })

    const videoName = "x.mp4"
    const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET
    const SNSTOPIC = process.env.SNSTOPIC
    const IAM_ROLE_ARN = process.env.IAM_ROLE_ARN
    const startDetectParams = {
      FaceAttributes: "ALL",
      Video: {
        S3Object: {
          Bucket: BUCKET,
          Name: videoName,
        },
      },
      notificationChannel: {
        roleARN: IAM_ROLE_ARN,
        SNSTopicArn: SNSTOPIC,
      },
    }

const data = await client.send(
      new StartFaceDetectionCommand(startDetectParams)
    )
```

I believe this code snippet is correct. However, despite the `client.send` line, the SNS topic does not receive the results.

I haven't created the Lambda function to save the results into DynamoDB yet.

For now, my goal is to only observe the result in the SNS topic